# How to count the occurrence of an object in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I have a set of images of colored shapes from which I want to count the occurrence of a blue square, of which I have a template image. Currently, my idea is to extract from the image a binary image containing only the blue shapes and then using the binarized template to count the occurrence, but I am unsure as to how to do the second half of this. Here is my current working code:

```
clear;

I1 = imread("im1.jpg");
I2 = imread("im2.jpg");
I3 = imread("im3.jpg");
temp = imread("temp.png");

% Get the image color chanels
Ir1 = I1(:,:,1);
Ig1 = I1(:,:,2);
Ib1 = I1(:,:,3);

Ir2 = I2(:,:,1);
Ig2 = I2(:,:,2);
Ib2 = I2(:,:,3);

Ir3 = I3(:,:,1);
Ig3 = I3(:,:,2);
Ib3 = I3(:,:,3);

% Get blue only
IBlue1 = Ib1 - Ir1 - Ig1;
IBlue2 = Ib2 - Ir2 - Ig2;
IBlue3 = Ib3 - Ir3 - Ig3;

% Dilate, erode and fill holes
se = strel('disk', 15);
IBlue1 = imfill(imerode(imdilate(IBlue1, se),se),'holes') > 0;
IBlue2 = imfill(imerode(imdilate(IBlue2, se),se),'holes') > 0;
IBlue3 = imfill(imerode(imdilate(IBlue3, se),se),'holes') > 0;
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

My issue is that the shapes can overlap, such as in `im2` and `im3` which can make it hard to find the square. Additionally, I am unsure as to how to count the number of squares? Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to erode first, then dilate maybe? Or to erode a bit more than what you dilate. The prolems in the shapes that overlap is that you are making the shapes "inflate" (dilate) and then remove stuff, but that joins them together

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain myself well. What I meant is that in `im2` and `im3` the blue square is hidden underneath other shapes, so can only be partially seen. My question is how can I match a partial square with the template square?

Comment: 3D template matching is a big field, you will definitely need much, much more code than what is possible here

Comment: I think it's a heavy deep learning task. You can cover a blue rectangle with some other shape that only a blue triangle remains visible. In a picture taken from top with no shadows, like the rightmost one, you cannot distinguish such shape from a triangle using IP techniques. Even with a deep net you will have serious problems detecting this rectangle.

Comment: no amount of deep learning can see what isn't there to see. if you want to match partial shapes when you know what shapes must be there, that's already doable without deep learning.